# Unable to addChild on MouseCoordinations

Tags: actionscript-3

What i am trying to do is, to place a new tower each time on MouseX and MouseY. but it seems it isn't working Any Idea guys?

or if you can create a tileMap array and add new child of PrototypeTower each time when we click on the Tower (on x=50, y=400) to select and place wherever we want. When i click the the box at x=50, y=400, the startDrag() doesn't work.

**Main.as**

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var  pTower:PrototypeTower = new PrototypeTower;
        private var zTower:PrototypeTower = new PrototypeTower;
        private var fTower:PrototypeTower = new PrototypeTower;
        public function Main() 
        {
            pTower.x = 50;
            pTower.y = 400;
            addChild(pTower);

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }
        private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

            pTower.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClicked);
        }
        private function onClicked(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClicked);

            zTower.x = mouseX;
            zTower.y = mouseY;
            addChild(zTower);
            zTower.startDrag();

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlaced);
        }
        private function onPlaced(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlaced);
            zTower.stopDrag();
            fTower.x = mouseX
            fTower.y = mouseY;

            addChild(fTower);

        }
    }
}
```

**PrototypeTower.as**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class PrototypeTower extends MovieClip 
    {   
        public function PrototypeTower() 
        {
            this.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
            this.graphics.drawRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
            this.graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you, i am totally noob, wondering around from days!

Comment: "*but it seems it isn't working*" what exactly is not working?

Comment: @null correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't he need to set a `graphics.lineStyle` before drawing a rectangle?

Comment: @Neal Davis only if you want to set a line style. For a fill without a line, no line style should be specified, which is equivalent to omitting the call to that function.

Comment: @null thanks. That's one line of code I can remove from almost all my projects!! Haha

Comment: @null 
When i click the the box at x=50, y=400... the startDrag() doesn't works

Comment: What is your end goal? Big picture first. Why do you have zTower and fTower?

Comment: They are temp, as you can see they are same movieclip... i just want a code where i can add as many towers i want, anywhere on map (after i click that tower at  x=50, y=400) and click anywhere to place

Comment: You say the start drag doesn't work. Does that mean that the tower is appearing but just doesn't follow the mouse? Or is it not being added to the stage at all?

Comment: Tower is added, just not following the mouse, it appears below pTower (which is already on frame)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is just a schematic for now. I'll try to refine it later if you need. Hopefully this clears some things up for you though

When you click the tower, add a new tower at the `x,y` of the mouse and do some sort of `startDrag(tower)` on the new tower you just added. Then when you click on the stage, stop the drag and set the new X,y

**edit**

You might try getting rid of all your removeEventListener calls

I think your problem is you are removing the event listener that gets added in your main function. Keep in mind that the main function (class constructor) for the document class only gets called **once**, so you add an event listener for `ADDED_TO_STAGE` only once, and then you remove it the first time you try to add anything to the stage, and you never put it back. Just don't remove it in the first place.

You are calling `zTower.startDrag()` before you add it to the stage. Do `addChild(zTower)` and *then* `zTower.startDrag()`

Comment: Yeah that is what i asked for.. but the problem is... `zTower.startDrag();` isn't working .. can you please make a script?.. second most, when we click on the New tower (we have added on stage) it should have a "remove" button right below it.. and when we click on stage back (instead of clicking remove button) it should remove that button (floating below the tower)

Comment: Check my edited answer. I think I noticed your problem.

Comment: `zTower.startDrag();` isn't working even after removing `removeEventListener()`

Comment: New edit is not working either, please try it in your FD.. you will know that i have did all that, still not helping

instead of fixing my problem, you should do a thing. Imagine you are creating it.. how will you create it?  A: a button that will select a character(movieClip), B: a stage Where you can add that character after you have selected it (using A)

Comment: I understand. I can't since I'm at work. But I'll try tonight.

Comment: You there?? @Neal Davis